# Resistor value calculation

Tags: resistors

What is the role of these two resistor please tell me that Why is first resistor 1 mega ohm the second is 100 k ? what formula has been used in this circuit to calculate first resistor and second one and also tell me what if both resistor are not used ? forgot to tell you the role of the circuit is to detect static electricity and magnetic field thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The transistors in the circuit are in a Darlington configuation, which means that the signal that goes into the first amplifier is greatly amplified.

The form of transistor biasing that is used here seems to be fixed bias, or base bias.

Here are some equations that would apply here (for each transistor):

\$I_C = \beta I_B\$

\$V_{CE} = V_{CC} − I_C R_C\$

The first transistors must amplify a very, *very* weak current. The beta (\$\beta\$) for these transistors probably ranges from 75 to 200, which means that the large resistor allows the the transistor to turn on. If the resistor was tiny or non-existent, it would change the bias of the transistor and cause it to have a hard time turning on.

Also, the resistors help limit current. In the event that there was no current limit the first transistor is turned on, that would possibly destroy the first two transistors because a lot of charge will flow from \$V_{CC}\$ (6 volts) to ground.